# Phone Gap with Jquery Mobile won't open internal links

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a phone gap application with jquery mobile and I can get external links to work and single page navigation working but I cannot open another file in my application.  All the files are located in the www folder.  The error message is "Failed to load webpage with error: The requested URL was not found on this server.  If i comment out the jquery-1.6.4.min.js file it will work but that's not a good solution.  I've tried rel="external" and several other things I've seen by googling but nothing seems to work

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title></title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,
   user-scalable=no;" />

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="include/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
   <script src="include/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="include/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">


    function onBodyLoad()

    {

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

     }

    function onDeviceReady()

    {
    //do something


    }



    </script>

    </head>
   <body onload="onBodyLoad()">
   <div data-role="page" id="manage">    

      <div data-role="content" id="inputs">
         <a href="about.html">About</a>

      </div>

   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you update your PhoneGap manifest. Look for PhoneGap.plist, open it and look for ExternalHosts. You need to add the urls one by one, or you can simply add "*". This will allow the use of all urls within the application. PhoneGap blocks all urls by default.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.  If i take out the jquery script references and just go with straight phonegap it doesn't have a problem

Comment: Have you also tried mixing up the order of the javascript includes? In my own files i have this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.1.min.css" />      
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>`